# Passing information between entities from a Doctrine Event in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a listener with doctrine events like this:

```
class myListener
{
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
    {
            $entity = $args->getObject();

        if ($entity instanceof Item) {
            if ($entity->futureDate) {
                $this->doSomethingInTheFuture($entity);
            } else {
              $this->doSomethingNow($entity)
            }
        }

        if ($entity instanceof ImageOfItem) {
            if (/*It is in the future*/) {
            $this->doSomethingElseInTheFuture($entity); //This is where I am stucked
            } else {
            $this->doSomethingElseNow($entity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have two functions for each entity depending if it will be done in the future or now.

Only the entity Item has the field "futureDate". If the entity Item has Future Date, ImageOfItem should also call the `doSomethingElseInTheFuture` function when called. They are both called after one another in the controller. However I find no way to communicate between eachother in the listener.

Is there a way to give ImageOfItem a condition depending if Item has the propierty futureDate or not in the Listener, while they are both called in the same Controller?

Comment: What do you think about creating your own event ? Like 'item.created' and passing some data to your event listener (futureDate and the created entity for example) ?
See https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher.html

Comment: @BwaBwa That's what I am currently planning to do but it would be much better if there was a way to use already existing events.

Comment: Does ImageOfItem have a relationship with Item? If yes you can replace `if (/*It is in the future*/)` by something like `If ($entity->getItem()->futureDate)`

Comment: May be by doing an association between Item and ImageOfItem like @acucchieri proposition answer